# Shear in Summation Convention

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the linear map for fixed $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \lambda\in\Bbb{R}$ where a and b are orthogonal unit vectors:

$$ S: \vec{x}\to \vec{x'} = \vec{x}+\lambda(\vec{b}.\vec{x})\vec{a} $$

I am looking to turn the map into a matrix $S_{ij}$ in terms of the components of $a$ and $b$ such that $x'_i=S_{ij}x_j$

I have worked out it is a shear but cannot figure out how to represent it using summation convention.
I would appreciate an explicit solution, as I cannot solve any problems of this form.
I understand how to use $\delta_{ij}$ and $\varepsilon_{ijk}$ though, so no need to explain them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $b\cdot x=b^Tx$ is a scalar, then
$$S(x)=x+\lambda b^Txa=x+\lambda ab^Tx=(I+\lambda ab^T)x$$
which implies $S=I+\lambda ab^T$. Or
$$x'^i=S^i_jx^j=(\delta^i_j+\lambda a^ib_j)x^j$$

Comment: I am confused by the notation $b^T$, what does it describe? I assumed transpose, but can b^T x be represented as dimensionless?

Comment: @Dangercrow $b^T$ is the transpose of $b$

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide a resource which explains why $b^Tx=b.x$ is a scalar. EDIT: More specifically why we can write $b.x$ in the form $b^Tx$

Comment: @Dangercrow inner product is always a scalar, isn't it? Moreover, both $b\cdot x$ and $b^Tx$, using summation convention, is $b_ix^i$.